# tryCatch issue with an API

Tags: r

I am having a problem with a tryCatch, and the great pre-existing guides on SO do not seem to have the fix I am looking for.

Libraries and filtering.

```
library(RNRCS)
library(metScanR)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
    
NRCS <- getNetwork(network = 'NRCS')

dt = rbindlist(
  lapply(NRCS, function(x) data.table(t(x))),
  fill = TRUE)

dt <- dt %>%
  tidyr::unnest(identifiers) %>% 
  filter(idType == 'SNTL') %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(elements) %>% 
  filter(element == "snow depth") %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(location, names_repair = "unique") %>% 
  filter(latitude_dec >= 36.5 & latitude_dec <= 41.5) %>% 
  filter(longitude_dec >= -110.0 & longitude_dec <= -104.0) %>% 
  dplyr::select(namez, idType, id, platform, latitude_dec, longitude_dec, elev, state, county)

Snotel_ids <- dt %>%
  mutate(id =  as.numeric(id)) %>% 
  pull(id)
```

So I have used Trycatches around a dozen times to varying success, but I cannot figure out this problem. The function just stops running instead of reporting the error and continuing.

```
snow_shovelling_months <- rbindlist(lapply(Snotel_ids[116:120], function(x){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      intermediate <- grabNRCS.data(network="SNTL", site_id = x, timescale = "monthly", DayBgn = '1900-01-01', DayEnd = '2020-05-01')
      intermediate <- intermediate %>% dplyr::select(Date, Snow.Depth..in..Start.of.Month.Values)
      intermediate <- intermediate %>% mutate(site_id = x)
      out <- intermediate %>% dplyr::rename(Snow_depth = 'Snow.Depth..in..Start.of.Month.Values')
    },
    error = function(cond){
      message(paste("Site caused an error:", x))
      message(cond)
      return(NA)
    },
    warning = function(cond){
      message(paste("Site emits a warning:", x))
      message(cond)
      return(NA)
    },
    finally = {
      return(out)
        }
      )
    }
  )
)
```

I have used most combinations of having the error and warning functions being (e) & (w), not having a message, and returning Null, in those sections. But I always end up with an error:

```
Site caused an error: 305 # my message to console. 
no lines available in inputError in tryCatch(expr = { : object 'out' not found
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? This format tends to work with API's but it is just being sticky.

**EDIT**

After spending a lot of time with r2evans suggestion of withCallingHandlers and reviewing Ch.9 of Advanced R a few times I realized, this could be accomplished with less code. To find the missing sites I an anti-join downstream of this

```
  snow_shovelling_months <- function(x){
  try({
      intermediate <- grabNRCS.data(network="SNTL", site_id = x, timescale = "monthly", DayBgn = '1900-01-01', DayEnd = '2020-05-01')
      intermediate <- intermediate %>% dplyr::select(Date, Snow.Depth..in..Start.of.Month.Values)
      intermediate <- intermediate %>% mutate(site_id = x)
      out <- intermediate %>% dplyr::rename(Snow_depth = 'Snow.Depth..in..Start.of.Month.Values')
    },
    silent = TRUE
  )
}

snow_depth <- lapply(Snotel_ids, snow_shovelling_months)
snow_depth <- keep(snow_depth, ~ length(.x) > 1)
snow_depth_monthly <- rbindlist(snow_depth)
```

Comment: `tryCatch` doesn't *muffle* warnings; when a warning is received, it **stops** execution of the expression and does something with the warning, and it never goes back to continue. If you want to completely hide it, then `suppressWarnings`. If you want to do something with the warning and then continue, consider `withCallingHandlers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time with r2evans suggestion of withCallingHandlers and reviewing Ch.9 of Advanced R a few times I realized, this could be accomplished with less code. To find the missing sites I an anti-join downstream of this

```
snow_shovelling_months <- function(x){
  try({
      intermediate <- grabNRCS.data(network="SNTL", site_id = x, timescale = "monthly", DayBgn = '1900-01-01', DayEnd = '2020-05-01')
      intermediate <- intermediate %>% dplyr::select(Date, Snow.Depth..in..Start.of.Month.Values)
      intermediate <- intermediate %>% mutate(site_id = x)
      out <- intermediate %>% dplyr::rename(Snow_depth = 'Snow.Depth..in..Start.of.Month.Values')
    },
    silent = TRUE
  )
}

snow_depth <- lapply(Snotel_ids, snow_shovelling_months)
snow_depth <- keep(snow_depth, ~ length(.x) > 1)
snow_depth_monthly <- rbindlist(snow_depth)
```